# work with d.ts with a different folder for js (pdfjs-dist)

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Currently pdfjs-dist https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/tree/bd2a6cd87f9e0c3a9b3197d5d27acfb99886629b contains
the d.ts and js files in separate folders:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/blob/bd2a6cd87f9e0c3a9b3197d5d27acfb99886629b/types/src/display/node_utils.d.ts

https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/blob/bd2a6cd87f9e0c3a9b3197d5d27acfb99886629b/lib/display/node_utils.js

If i import them with:

```typescript
import { NodeCanvasFactory } from 'pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/node_utils';
```

it generates wrong js code:

```js
const api_1 = require('pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api');
```

Is it possible to properly map the d.ts along with js?

The result should be the following:

```js
const api_1 = require("pdfjs-dist/lib/display/api");
```

I also tried to work with tsconfig.json

```json
"paths": {
  "pdfjs-dist/types/src/*": ["./pdfjs-dist/lib/*"]
}
```

Full tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "types": [
            "node",
            "jest"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "paths": {
            "pdfjs-dist/types/src/*": ["./pdfjs-dist/lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules", 
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I experienced some issues the other day like this one, I found an issue in the `@types/pdfjs-dist` package that for reasons I was not able to resolve the types for my usages `PdfPageProxy` `PdfDocumentProxy`, so I went with copying the types and creating a new file in my project `types.d.ts` and defining them there and using them in my project as definitions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with for the same problem. (In your question you were mixing `api` and `node_utils`, but will answer assuming you want to import `node_utils`).

First, create a declaration file named `node_utils.d.ts` (Note that the name of the file has to be the same as the module name).

In this file add the following:

```
declare module 'pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils' {
    export * from 'pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/node_utils'
}
```

Now you can use `pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils` when importing like below and Typescript will be pick up the declaration files. Unfortunately, this has to be done for every file you want to import that has typing in separate folders from the js files!

```
import { NodeCanvasFactory } from 'pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils';
```